# method to return false - conditional

Tags: java, methods, return, charat

I have constructed the below method, but I need the method to return as false, if the ID length is not 7 characters long.

I believe I need to define the length somewhere in here as 7 (but I could be wrong in my understanding here) and I think I might be missing a return statement?

Any ideas?

```
 public void validIdd()
 {
 int nameLenght = id.length();
for(int i = 0; i < nameLenght ; i++) {
    char character = id.charAt(i);
    int ascii = (int) character; 
    int ch = ascii % 10; 
    int total = ch;
}
```

Comment: You should change the method signature first of all to return boolean rather than void.

Comment: also you need to pass the id as a parameter. ex. public boolean validId(String id) {        return id.length() != 7;}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question. It seems that you're just generally confused and looking for pointers fixing up the code; that's not something we can help you with because we expect *specific* questions (and every specific question that could be extracted here has already been asked and answered many times). This is *not a discussion forum*; please try Reddit or Quora for this kind of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First change the return type to boolean and pass the id as a parameter.
Check if the id has a length of 7.

```
public boolean validIdd(String id)
 {
 int nameLenght = id.length();
 if(nameLength != 7) return false;
 for(int i = 0; i < nameLenght ; i++) {
    char character = id.charAt(i);
    int ascii = (int) character; 
    int ch = ascii % 10; 
    int total = ch;
 }
 return true;
}
```

If you want to return the `total` variable you have to set the return type to `int` and if the length is less than 7 you have to return either `null` or a value which can not be created like for example `-1`